# FreeImage and wxWidgets conflict?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, conflict, freeimage

As soon as I built the FreeImaged.lib and `#include`d `FreeImage.h` linked it to my ***WORKING*** wxWidgets + OpenCV dependent project, I got errors mainly in two files: `init.h` and `atomic.h`.

Most of the errors state that:

- `HINSTANCE` is undefined
- `wxEntry` already defined as function
- `wxEntryStart` already defined as function
- `InterlockedDecrement` is undefined

If I comment out the `#include <FreeImage.h>` then all the errors are gone. Why does this happen? How can I fix this?

Comment: HINSTANCE and InterlockedDecrement are Windows API functions and types.  They are not related to FreeImage.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah... I changed `#include "afxres.h"` to `#include <windows.h>` (I'm using VS2013) in OpenEXR, one of the FreeImage dependencies. that might be related to this issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors are probably due to `#include <windows.h>` somewhere in FreeImage. Include wxWidgets headers first, they take care to neutralize most of the harmful definitions in `<windows.h>`. If you have to include the other one first, include `<wx/msw/winundef.h>` immediately after it to undefine them.

If this doesn't help, you really should update your question with the *precise* errors you're getting (at least the first one or two).